# can't get react-grid-gallery to display local image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I'm showing an image gallery using [react-grid-gallery](https://github.com/benhowell/react-grid-gallery). The code works fine when I use an URL, but I haven't found any way to use a local image. Is this possible?

**Intended:**

```js
import Img1 from './imgs/img1.jpg'
import Img2 from './imgs/img2.jpg'

const IMAGES = [{
      src: {Img1},
      thumbnail: {Img1},
      thumbnailWidth: 350,
      thumbnailHeight: 250
},
{
      src: {Img2},
      thumbnail: {Img2},
      thumbnailWidth: 350,
      thumbnailHeight: 250
},
```

**Intended usage:**

```js
return(
    <div className="gallery-wrapper">
      {
        <Gallery images={IMAGES}
               enableLightbox={false}
               enableImageSelection={true}
               onClickThumbnail = {this.onSelectImage}
               thumbnailstyle = {this.styleSmall}/>
      }
    </div>
)
```

This results in the following error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `images[0].src` of type `object` supplied to `Gallery`, expected `string`.
    in Gallery (at App.js:331)
    in App (at src/index.js:7) index.js:1375
    e index.js:1375
    printWarning checkPropTypes.js:21
    checkPropTypes checkPropTypes.js:76
    React 2
    render App.js:329
    React 15
    js index.js:7
    Webpack 7
```

Ideas?

Comment: You are declaring your src is as an object `src: {Img1},`

Comment: take out the curly braces when you declare src: {Img2}. just declare it like src: Img2

Comment: Wow thanks, you're a life saver! I searched all over for so long for that